# Making connection between two tables in php

Tags: php, sql, database, commerce

i am creating a basic insert product page in ecommerce website(admin panel)

where i have a table `category` (with  `male` or  `female`)
then a `man` table  in which i put product category like grooming kit watches etc
same in `female` table (makeup item and dresses etc)

and third table `product` where all product where all products would be inserted okay

so now i want to link them in such a way that (suppose a drop down interface)

in category i select male 
then it take id of male from "category" table  suppose it 1
and then from another dropdown of "male" table if i select grooming kit which has id suppose 1 there 
the product table take these id's from these table automatically...
for example 
i am describing table structure

```
CATEGORY
CAT_ID   CAT_TITLE      *(cat_id to auto increment so if i add kids = 3 )
1            MALE
2           FEMALE

MALE
M_ID      M_TITLE     *M_ID auto increment
1           GROOMING KIT
2           WATCHES

FEMALE                *f_id auto increment
F_ID      F_TITLE
1          DRESSES
2          SHOES
```

product
`p_id(*auto increment)  CAT_ID(*must auto matically take id from category)  g_id(*must take id from male or female title)`

so that i know where to insert product on page

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with the database structure, even before we get into coding.

Remove the MALE and FEMALE tables and use only the PRODUCT table.  Then add a foreign key from PRODUCT to CATEGORY.  Like so:

```
CATEGORY
Cat_id: primary key
Cat_title: male or female

PRODUCT
Product_id: primary key
Product_name
Product_price
... other product fields ...
Product_Cat: foreign key to CATEGORY:Cat_id
```

This way you will be able to work on all your products from a single table (ex. sort by price, without regards to the Category).

In your queries you will have to join PRODUCT and CATEGORY together to get male or female products only.

Also if you add a new Category, you will not have to create new tables, just add products with the new Cat_id.

The advantages for the future are plentiful!

Comment: but see the product can also have different variety like in mens category i put a typwe of product grooming kit now grooming kit it self have so many variety  according to your answer  i can add mal female category and their respective product but i want to go like this                   ........... male female then in prod category gorrming kitr and watches(for male) then even grooming kit and watches have their sub categories.........

Comment: Hum, that is not listed in the original question.  You will have to create a new question with all the details.  The setup of a database is near impossible with only a partial listing of requirements.

Comment: $get_cat = "select * from category  inner join mcat on category.cat_id = mcat.cat inner join kcat on category.cat_id = kcat.cat inner join fcat on category.cat_id = fcat.cat ";           i am using this to join these table not working but when i joion two tables they work    i added a column "cat" in both male and femlae which is foreign key with cat_id in category